# obtained unreasonable result using ld_clump function in ieugwasr

Tags: r

We'd like to use ld_clump function in ieugwasr to select independent SNPs (LD clumping). There are 8 SNPs in our data, as following:

CHR SNP BP A1 TEST NMISS BETA STAT pval rsid

3 3:30061270:C:A 30061270 A ADD 171 130.2 5.919 1.93E-08 rs147822168

3 3:30094932:C:T 30094932 T ADD 171 130.2 5.919 1.93E-08 rs141676985

3 3:30151257:T:C 30151257 C ADD 171 107.2 5.753 4.39E-08 rs369713911

3 3:30155667:GTTTCCAAAGTCTTTTTTCATCTGT:G 30155667 G ADD 171 107.2 5.753 4.39E-08 rs979225690

3 3:30155691:T:G 30155691 G ADD 171 107.2 5.753 4.39E-08 rs542824790

8 8:3947590:T:A 3947590 A ADD 171 182.3 5.899 2.13E-08 rs193072510

10 10:114859251:A:G 114859251 A ADD 171 130.7 7.556 3.09E-12 rs6585206

17 17:19349093:T:C 19349093 C ADD 171 131.4 5.975 1.46E-08 rs118061465

There are 5 SNPs from chromosome 3, and the other 3 SNPs are in different chromosome (8, 10 and 17). We expected that the other 3 SNPs will be kept in the final result because they are the only one SNP in chromosome 8, 10 and 17, respectively. However, we found that it only included one SNP, rs6585206 in chromosome 10, in the final result. We do't understand why we obtained this unreasonable result. We used the R code: ld_clump(data,clump_r2 = 0.2). There is no error or warning in the log. What can I do to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The SNPs on chromosome 3 could have been pruned if they were in LD with each other based on the parameters in the `ld_clump` function. You may have lost the lead SNP on chr3, in addition to the SNPs on chr8 and 17, if these **were not in the reference panel** to which the `ld_clump` function refers. The default reference panel is the EUR super-population from the 1000 Genomes Project.